# Find which frame the current fragment is displayed in

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an issue with fragment navigation in frame-layouts. Namely I cannot find out in which frame the fragment is currently being displayed in.

My setup is the following:
I have 3 parent fragments (PA, PB, PC), each with their own unique framelayouts. Additionally I have 3 Childfragments (CA,CB, CC) and two Grandchildfragments (GA, GB)

The parent fragments call the childfragments into the appropriate framelayouts (works fine), but now I want the childfragments to replace themselves with the appropriate grandchildren, but I have no way of finding out in which framelayout the childfragments are currently displayed in. (I hope that makes sense)

Pseudo-code example:

```
 public class Parent extends Fragment{

 //lots of stuff here
 public void replaceFragmentWithChild(){
      Fragment frg = new childFragment();
      FragmentManager mgr = ((FragmentActivity) getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction trx = mgr.beginTransaction();
      trx.addToBackStack(null);
      trx.replace(R.id.content_view_a, childFragment).commit();
 }
 }

public class Child extends Fragment{
//lots of stuff here

     public void replaceFragmentWithGrandChild(){
          Fragment frg = new GrandChildFragment();
          FragmentManager mgr = ((FragmentActivity) getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();
          FragmentTransaction trx = mgr.beginTransaction();
          trx.addToBackStack(null);
          //here is the problem. I would like to call trx.replace(GET-CURRENT-CONTENT-VIEW, frg)
          trx.replace(???, frg).commit();
     }}
```

Any input would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** Ok, I have found a possible solution by saving the ViewGroup Container in the onCreateView and passing that to the trx.replace function.
But unfortunately I am getting the following Message:     `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0057 (de.tel.quenference.activities:id/sara_content_view) for fragment PaperviewFragment{421da470 #2 id=0x7f0c0057}` which makes little sense to me, because the view is the same one I am in,or?
What am I missing?

Comment: Why you can'y usee R.id.content_view_a? It you display child fragment in this frame, then you should replace content in R.id.content_view_a with grandchild

Comment: That doesn't work, since I never know in which content frame the grandchildfragment should be placed in, I can't define it statically. I need the grandchildfragment to replace the childfragment no matter in which frame_layout the childfragment is currently in.

Comment: Then remove child fragment at first and then add grandchild fragment

Comment: Well replace should actually do the removing (since replace is simply a remove and then add), but it simply displays the new fragment on top of the old one. So now I have overlapping fragments.

Comment: it's replace fragments if they attached in the same container, in your case as I understand your fragments placed in different containers

Comment: Ah, sorry. Then I was not clear. My Problem is that a childfragment should replace itself with the grandchildfragment. So the grandchildfragment ends up in the same container as the ChildFragment.

Comment: Ok, then you did smth wrong, because it should work, I just test it, and it's hard to say what without code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out and I sort of want to shoot myself.
First off, the '`No View Found`' error stems from the fact, that my parentfragment did not call `transaction.addToBackStack` (I added it into my example code but not my production code...)

Just putting that in unfortunately did not fix everything, but I had to also change the ParentFragment to not call `getChildFragmentManager`, but rather the normal `FragmentManager`
otherwise the grandchildfragment would not appear in the frameLayout.

Basically my working code looks like this:

```
public class Parent extends Fragment{

 //lots of stuff here
 public void replaceFragmentWithChild(){
      Fragment frg = new childFragment();
      FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      trx.addToBackStack(null);
      trx.replace(R.id.content_view_a, childFragment).commit();
 }
 }

public class Child extends Fragment{
private ViewGroup locContainer;
//lots of stuff here
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        locContainer = container;
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }    

     public void replaceFragmentWithGrandChild(){
          Fragment frg = new GrandChildFragment();
          FragmentTransaction trx = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          trx.addToBackStack(
          trx.replace(locContainer.getId(), frg).commit();
     }}
```